# nhibernate Instantiate an item that inherit from other item

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two classes, `Item` and `SoldItem`. `SoldItem` inherits from `Item` adding some property such as prize, solddate, etc.

First I create a `Item`, and when i sold it I want to create `solditem`. Is correct this design? if yes how I can create solditem starting from item?

Comment: Just curious why don't you create class Item only with property IsSold ?

Comment: @ktutnik because SoldItem have more properties ininfluent for Item, such as SoldDate, Reference to Invoice, Reference to sold tracking system, a SoldPrize different from proposed Prize, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this is improper use of inheritance. What if you need to diversify the `Item` into subclasses by some feature that is orthogonal to whether it has been sold? For example, if you sell software, an item could be shipped on physical media, it could be downloadable, or it could be a subscription; if you decide to model these out by using inheritance as well, you already have six classes. And each orthogonal feature you add becomes a multiplier to the number of classes you need.

A better design, involving composition, would be to have separate `Item` and `Sale` classes, and a link between the two; then you can add functionality to the `Item` class to get the relevant `Sale`, if any, and vv., get the `Item` of `Sale` (which should always be non-null). In this context, thinking relational rather than object-oriented is probably a better approach.

If you are only interested in sold items, you'd look at `Sale` objects directly, getting item information through the related `Item`. If you are interested in any item, get an `Item` instance, and if needed query it for a `Sale`.

Comment: the item is only one and not a kind of product, it have a unique code that itentify the exact one item. this is why originally i thought at inhetitance. but you're right, is better a one-to-one link because otherwise i can't navigate from item to solditem.